# Prove series is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$ (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

> Define a mapping $$f(z)=\cot(z)-\frac {1}{z}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {2z}{z^2-n^2\pi^2}$$
>
> Show that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$

I am trying to derive the Euler factorization of $\sin(z)=z\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac {z^2}{n^2\pi^2})$

I was able to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {2z}{z^2-n^2\pi^2}$ converges locally uniformly (i.e. compactly converges on $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:z\not\in n\pi, n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$), and that $f(z)$ has removable singularities at $n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, which I will use later to derive the Euler factorization.

I am not really sure how to bound $f$ though, and I have a suspicion that $f(z)=0$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose that you meant $\cot(z)$ instead of $\cot(t)$.

Comment: My apologies, yes I do. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula summation (together with 1/z) is in fact the Mittag Leffler expansion of $cot z$. So your guess is right, $f$ is indeed zero. To show this, let $g(z):=\frac{\pi}{z^2-a^2}cot \pi z$ where $a\notin \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gamma_n$ be the square contour of length $n$ centered at the origin, i.e. $\gamma_n$ has vertices $[(n+\frac{1}{2})+i(n+\frac{1}{2}), (n+\frac{1}{2})-i(n+\frac{1}{2}), -(n+\frac{1}{2})-i(n+\frac{1}{2}), -(n+\frac{1}{2})+i(n+\frac{1}{2})]$. First show the following:

a) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\gamma_n}g(z)dz=0$

b) Now compute the integral $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\gamma_n}g(z)dz=0$ directly using the residue theorem, i.e. find the residues of $g(z)$. The poles of $g(z)$ are exactly at $z=\pm a$ and the integers.

With this, you can get the desired summation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I haven't done any Mittlag Leffler expansions. Could you please explain?

Comment: I have edited my post adding more details on the exercise. Of course this is just one of the many methods on showing the expansion of $\cot \pi z$.  Alternatively, you can check out https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Cotangent_Function